# If a string is an array of char, how do you convert it into an array of interger

Tags: c++

I kept getting an error with this loop. If there are something i missed, please help. Thank You!

```
int main(){
 string hasil;
 int cod[5];
 hasil = "99999";

 for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
     cod[i] = stoi(hasil[i]);
 }

 for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
     cout << cod[i] + 1;
 }
```

Comment: Please include the error you get in the question.

Comment: In the first `for` loop, instead of using `stoi`, use `cod[i] = hasil[i] - '0';`. Of course, you should first check if the character is actually a digit like `hasil[i] >= '0' && hasil[i] <= '9'`

Comment: `stoi` converts an entire string to an int. However, you give it a single character. Do you want to convert each character to an int?

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. @kiner_shah, Yes, the input will always be a string consisting of 5 digit numbers. And for the error that i got is, " error: no matching function for call to 'stoi(__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char>, char>::value_type&)'| ".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::stoi()` takes a `std::string`, not a `char`. But `std::string` does not have a constructor that takes *only* a single `char`, which is why your code fails to compile.

Try one of these alternatives instead:

```cpp
cod[i] = stoi(string(1, hasil[i]));
```

```cpp
cod[i] = stoi(string(&hasil[i], 1));
```

```cpp
string s;
s = hasil[i];
cod[i] = stoi(s);
```

```cpp
char arr[2] = {hasil[i], '\0'};
cod[i] = stoi(arr);
```

Answer (score 4):

`stoi` is for converting entire strings to integers, but you're only giving it single characters.

You could either build strings from each character like so:

```cpp
cod[i] = std::stoi(std::string(1, hasil[i])); // the 1 means "repeat char one time"
```

Or calculate the actual integer yourself using a bit of ascii math (assuming everything is a valid digit):

```cpp
cod[i] = hasil[i] - '0'; // now '0' - '0' returns 0, '5' - '0' returns 5, etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

The [below](https://onlinegdb.com/h5yKnR-Yr) complete working program shows how you can achieve what you want:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
 std::string hasil;
 int cod[5];
 hasil = "99999";

for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    cod[i] = hasil[i] - '0';
}

 for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
     std::cout << cod[i];
 }
 
 return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/h5yKnR-Yr).

Answer (score 1):

`std::stoi` only accpet `std::string` or `std::wstring` as an argument type. But `hasil[i]` is a `char`

In C++, `'0'` to `'9'` is guarantee to be ascending in ACSII values, so, you can do this:

```cpp
cod[i] = hasil[i] - '0';
```